# How can I permalink answers on answers.microsoft.com?

Tags: microsoft-community

Is it possible to permalink to an answer on [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/)?

Take the answer below from "*[Using Windows 7, how do I run CHKDSK?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/using-windows-7-how-do-i-run-chkdsk/a68b3e4d-1a42-e011-9767-d8d385dcbb12)*" as an example. Clicking the author name goes to the user's profile page, while the post date shows an edit history, but neither offers a permalink option.

[image: Example answer from Microsoft Community]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution for Google Chrome (other browsers should be similar). I'm using [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update-insiderplat_pc/windows-update-windows-defender-definition-update/bc4cb18f-d812-44af-b515-f4e92ac453ba) as an example (the desired answer is the reply with the picture by LarryGriffiths).

1. Select some text in the desired answer
2. Right-click > Inspect (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
3. Navigate to the `div` that wraps the answer. Example:

```
    <div class="thread-message thread-message-enus" data-bi-area="33222377-d4df-4b79-9777-19a5cebdcb12" msgid="33222377-d4df-4b79-9777-19a5cebdcb12" msgparentid="1429f9aa-383b-49e3-bdc1-11646998c128" pagepos="1" msgpos="3" msgsection="Replies">
```

4. Copy the value of `msgid`.* Example:

```
    33222377-d4df-4b79-9777-19a5cebdcb12
```

5. Append `?messageId=`+`value` obtained above to the URL. And you're done. Example:

```
    ?messageId=33222377-d4df-4b79-9777-19a5cebdcb12
```

The end result: [permalink](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update-insiderplat_pc/windows-update-windows-defender-definition-update/bc4cb18f-d812-44af-b515-f4e92ac453ba?messageId=33222377-d4df-4b79-9777-19a5cebdcb12)!

**other attributes containing this value are `data-bi-area`, `data-bi-areaname`, `data-messageid`, `data-paneltarget`.*

Source: [social.microsoft.com](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d99e5b1-d272-4453-8446-d724d6d86868/how-can-i-link-specific-answers?#6f2369a6-ec59-4718-ab08-fd557efca95d) (valtih1978, November 2013)

This procedure was tested for answers.microsoft.com. For social.microsoft.com, the link above is an example itself.